# When to refer or address someone with their name

Tags: grammar, names

In Japanese you sometimes refer to people by name, even when talking directly to them.

Just curious if someone could give me a few examples of what this looks like when used in a conversation, as I've struggled to find any good examples.

Comment: Can you try to give an example sentence yourself?

Comment: 'sometimes'? I'd say almost always, barring some special circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can think of using a person's name to address them as the standard usage in Japanese.

**Example**

> 母親：「今から買い物に出かけるけど、太郎も来る？」
>  息子（太郎）：「うん、行く。」
>
> *Rōmaji*
>  Hahaoya: "Ima kara kaimono ni dekakeru kedo, Tarō mo
>   kuru?"
>  Musuko (Tarō): "Un, iku."
>
> *English translation*
>  Mom: "I'm going shopping. Would you like to
>   come too?"
>  Son (Taro): "Sure. I'd like to go."

Answer (score 2):

Suppose two girls, 美樹 and 理恵, are intimate friends.

美樹：私は友哉くんのことが好きだな。理恵は?
理恵：私は祐希くんがちょっと気になるな。

Miki: I like Tomoya . How about you?
Rie : I found Yuki something special.

if 美樹 says あなたは? insted of 理恵は?, it sounds quite unfriendly.